# Is $[0,\infty)$ the maximum candidate in $\mathbb{R}$ for the positive numbers?

Tags: ring-theory, number-systems

Let us regard $0$ as a positive number, at least for this question, and define that a subset $S$ of a ring $R$ is a *candidate for the positive numbers,* or simply a "candidate," iff

1. $S$ is a semiring: that is, $0 \in S$ and $S$ is closed under sums and products.
2. $x+y = 0$ implies $x = 0$ and $y = 0$, for all $x,y \in S$.

For example, taking $\mathbb{Z}$ as our ring $R$, we have that for all $n \in \mathbb{N},$ the following are candidates.

1. $\{m \in \mathbb{Z} \mid m \geq n\} \cup \{0\}$
2. $n \mathbb{N}.$

Furthermore, $\mathbb{N}$ is the *maximum* candidate.

*Proof*. Suppose towards a contradiction that some candidate $S \subseteq \mathbb{Z}$ has an element not in $\mathbb{N},$ call it $k$. Begin by observing the following.

1. Since $k \in S$, therefore $k^2 \in S$ (closure under products). Note also that $k^2$ is non-zero.
2. On the other hand, we have that since $k \in S$, therefore $-k^2 \in S,$ because $-k^2$ can be expressed as $|k|k,$ which is just a finite sum $k + \cdots + k$ (closure under sums).

Putting these together, we conclude that $k^2 = 0$ (since $x+y = 0$ implies $x=0$ for all $x,y \in S$). But this contradicts the observation that $k^2$ is non-zero.

**Question**. With a bit of prelude, the above argument basically works in $\mathbb{Q}$ as well. This reveals that $\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,\infty)$ is the maximum candidate in $\mathbb{Q}.$ Is $[0,\infty)$ the maximum candidate in $\mathbb{R}$? Does it even have one?

Comment: Better call a member of $[0,\infty)$ a *non-negative* number.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe, the problem, in brief, is that candidates $S \subseteq R$ give rise to partial orderings of $R$ in a natural way; but, since these are only *partial* orderings, there's a world of difference between the positive numbers with respect to this order, versus the non-negative numbers. Of course, of these were total orders, the only difference would be the inclusion or exclusion of $0$.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe, hence the first sentence of the question. By the way, I can give more details if you're interested.

Comment: A minor point: your example 1. is lacking the $0$ element if $n>0$. But you can add it in.

Comment: @HTFB, thanks! Completely slipped my mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your definition of a candidate is not dependent on $R$ at all.

If $t$ is an abstract transcendental element over $\mathbb{Q}$ then the polynomial semiring $\mathbb{N}[t]$ is a candidate. So if we choose a negative transcendental real value for $t$, say $-\pi$, then $\mathbb{N}[-\pi]$ is also a candidate.

And clearly $\mathbb{R}^+$ is a maximal candidate in $\mathbb{R}$ and does not contain $-\pi$. So there is no maximum candidate.

NB: It is not the case that we can extend $\mathbb{N}$ with any negative *irrational* element. Suppose, for example, $S$ contains $-\sqrt[3]{2}$. Then as $S$ is closed under multiplication, it also contains  $-\sqrt[3]{2} \times -\sqrt[3]{2} \times -\sqrt[3]{2} =-2$, and then axiom 2 is violated.

(I would guess that negative square roots, for example, would be permissible, but haven't worked this out fully, so I don't know what the strongest available result here is. All transcendental numbers *are* OK, though.)

Comment: What do you mean by the first sentence? $S$ is a subset of $R$.

Comment: If $S$ meets your conditions 1 and 2, then $S$ is a candidate in any $R$ of which it is a subset. We don't have to worry about how it is embedded in $R$, in other words. I mention this only to motivate the counterexample.

Comment: Okay, I think I get it now. But, why transcendental? I think that any (strictly negative) irrational number will suffice.

Comment: I've edited my answer to include an example of why this doesn't work.